# Draw polygon from given lines and latitudes

Tags: polygon, draw, shapes, qgis

I am trying to generate a polygon using two given lines (in this case are isobaths) and among two latitudes (33°S and 43°S) as northern and southern limits. I am using Qgis.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First draw an extent polygon for this two line,
Second crop extent polygon by this lines and delete outside areas.

If you want attributes in lines, try spatial join proccess.